# How does MongoDB keep data in sync

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Lets say I have a social media app.  There is a `Group` model that has a field called `invitedUsers` which is simply an array of user ids that are a part of that group.

On my backend I have a route that a user hits to join that `Group`.  In that route I do something like the following:

```
group.invitedUsers = lodash.concat(group.invitedUsers || [], userId)
group.save()
```

where `group` is the group that the user wants to join and `userId` is the id of the user that wants to join the group.  Upon save everything is updated properly and the user is now a part of the group.

But what happens if two users hit the route at exactly the same time?  How does MongoDB ensure that the `group` will always have both users ids added via the above method.  Is there not a chance that `group.invitedUsers` could be referencing a stale value if both these `group.save()` are being triggered around the same time?

Comment: Nothing is ever exactly the same time.  One of these transactions *will* be before the other.  Considering two different sessions if one writes a document and a second session reads it the second session will see the change.  If The second session reads before the first session has completed the update the second session will show the state of the record as it was the moment the read request was issued.  In your words, this might constitute stale.

Comment: Also, consider, are you doing a query, then an update?  If so, the queried data in one session can be stale the moment you collect it.  Other sessions can change that data.  Your fetched data is not a live representation of the data in the database.  If you want to ensure both sessions have added the data (and not removed any other elements) I recommend using an update command with $addToSet.  $addToSet differs from $push in that it will add the item if it does not already exist.  $push can add duplicates.

Comment: Also, consider what group.save() does.  This is not a MongoDB driver option, therefore it must be a framework option, like Springboot Spring Data.  Looks like mongoose in your case.  You want to avoid a document replacement vs. a targeted field update.  In otherwords, if you can update a field by itself while leaving the rest of the document intact, why replace the entire document.  Much more work on the database and corresponding components like replication to replace the document instead of updating a single field.

Comment: If you want to create this as an answer I can mark it as accepted. @barrypicker